# URL Rewrite (in Web.config) not redirecting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm trying to test URL Rewrite changing my Web.confing file.

I want to always redirect to `/arquivos`, as a test.

But nothing is happening.

Here's a part of my Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="CrawlerBotRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="/arquivos" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Comment: Do you have the UrlRewrite module installed? It isn't part of IIS by itself: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite - also, I'm not sure how smart URL rewrite is about not getting you stuck in a redirect loop.

Comment: I installed the module, still not doing anything :(